# Creating SQL Query references a few tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I tried to do this myself with views but I unfortunately I don't have the skills or knowledge required.

I've put in some dummy data to demonstrate.

uri of course = object_uri

**TABLE_RECORD**

```
+-----+---------------+---------+
| uri |     title     | client  |
+-----+---------------+---------+
|   1 | australia     | peter   |
|   2 | new zealand   | peter   |
|   3 | canada        | chris   |
|   4 | united states | mitch   |
|   5 | ireland       | michael |
|   6 | scotland      | mitch   |
+-----+---------------+---------+
```

**TABLE_UDF**

```
+------------+--------------+----------------+
| object_uri | udf_type_uri | udf_type_value |
+------------+--------------+----------------+
|          1 |         2005 | 1/12/2007      |
|          2 |         2005 | 2/04/2008      |
|          2 |         2006 | 3/04/2009      |
|          3 |         2005 | 4/05/2010      |
|          4 |         2006 | 12/04/2016     |
|          5 |         2005 | 14/05/2005     |
|          5 |         2006 | 14/05/2006     |
|          6 |         2005 | 20/01/2017     |
+------------+--------------+----------------+
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
+-----+---------------+---------+------------+------------+
| uri |     title     | client  | udf_type_1 | udf_type_2 |
+-----+---------------+---------+------------+------------+
|   1 | australia     | peter   | 1/12/2007  |            |
|   2 | new zealand   | peter   | 2/04/2008  | 3/04/2009  |
|   3 | canada        | chris   | 4/05/2010  |            |
|   4 | united states | mitch   |            | 12/04/2016 |
|   5 | ireland       | michael | 14/05/2005 | 14/05/2006 |
|   6 | scotland      | mitch   | 20/01/2017 |            |
+-----+---------------+---------+------------+------------+
```

Thanks heaps in advanced.

Comment: Where's your query?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is a `join` with conditional aggregation:

```
select r.uri, r.title, r.client,
       max(case when u.udf_type_uri = 2005 then udf_type_value end) as udf_type_1,
       max(case when u.udf_type_uri = 2006 then udf_type_value end) as udf_type_2
from record r join
     udf u
     on r.uri = u.object_uri
group by r.uri, r.title, r.client;
```

Comment: Is there any tangible performance impact in grouping by the composite key?  My gut instinct would be to group by the surrogate key, then join...

Comment: @MatBailie . . . Which performs better depends on a lot of factors -- whether the `join` filters out rows, the indexes on the tables, the relative sizes of the tables, . . .

Comment: But wouldn't those factors be the same in both cases?  You still joining the same tables, on the same keys, but one has been aggregated.  If there is an index on the uri, then it wouldn't be obfuscated for the purposes of the join?  But if there isn't an index, grouping by a surrogate key and two string properties seems, less than ideal?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_record
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        object_uri,
        MAX(CASE WHEN udf_type_uri = 2005 THEN udf_type_value END)   AS udf_type_1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN udf_type_uri = 2006 THEN udf_type_value END)   AS udf_type_2
    FROM
        table_udf
    GROUP BY
        object_uri
)
    table_udf
        ON  table_udf.object_uri = table_record.uri
```

The inner query squashes the `udf` table down to one row per `uri`, and uses `MAX()` and `CASE` to ensure the correct udf is placed in the correct column.  Then you just join the tables as normal.

*(Can also be done using `PIVOT`, but that's always seems clunkier to me...)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx*